# Worklight 6.1: Does the user to device mapping support multiple user map to single device

Tags: security, dictionary, ibm-mobilefirst, device

Referring to the link below:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc%2Fmonitor%2Fc_device_user_mapping.html

As far as I know, Worklight supports 1-to-1 user to device mapping. Is there any workaround to make it multiple user to device mapping instead?

One of the scenarios is where the same device is shared among a few employees.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no workaround for this. You can open a feature request for this if you're interested.

Edit: feature requests can be sent via http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/